# how to sniff MMS urls from a lot of HTTP links

Tags: networking

I have a text file that contains the HTTP urls for certain mp3 audio.  If I copy and paste the link to browser, the browser is going to return me a MMS link that I can use to download the streaming file.

But I have to copy and past each HTTP urls in order to sniff out the MMS link.  Could you please tell me if there is a way to convert all these HTTP urls (a few hundreds) into MMS urls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark to sniff and wget to generate the traffic, or use rtcpdump + lynx to download the files.

Comment: Given a text file with URLs, I doubt it gets any easier with using Wireshark to retrieve URLs.

Comment: @Lekensteyn he can sniff the http stream, then is just analyzing and extracting, no?

Comment: It /is/ possible, but it seems that it is about a HTTP Location redirect (guessed), in that case `curl -L` on all URLs is sufficient .